# Can't create new category in Wordpress - message “Could not insert term into the database"

Tags: database, wordpress, phpmyadmin, categories

I'm not a developer, but trying to solve a mystery lead me to this page. I've not been able to create new categories or menu suddenly and whenever I tried to do that returned a message:

> “Could not insert term into the database.”

Google search one thread suggested DB optimization plugin but did not work. Another one (https://www.reddit.com/r/Wordpress/comments/5iroaa/could_not_insert_term_into_the_database/) advised 3 things to do:

1. go to phpmyadmin then in Structure make sure AI is checked. Mine was not checked so I checked it, then tried to create a new category but now returned a message, "some error occurred. Please reload the page." I reloaded and the same message came back.
2. "stop playing in PhpMyAdmin and remove it from your server." I have no idea what this is about.
3. in Operations, set the number for auto-increment to be higher than your highest term_id. After I set the number and click on Save, an error message showed up at the bottom,

   > "Notice in .\tbl_operations.php#155 Undefined index: row_format
   > Backtrace"

This is my first WP site so it's still localhosted on my notebook. I reinstalled WP from scratch and imported the database but that did not help, either.

Hope all this makes some sense to someone here so can shed some light on my problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but just in case someone is having the same problem, here is how I fixed it. I am also completely new to SQL and website design, so beware when following my recommendations.

I got this error in WordPress and couldn't create categories. When searching for the problem, besides this question, I found the following threads (and played a lot in PhpMyAdmin, I simply ignored that Reddit comment):

- [Could not insert term into database](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/226245/could-not-insert-term-into-the-database). They advise to change the `AUTO_INCREMENT` option with `ALTER TABLE wp_terms AUTO_INCREMENT = 1` in the tables `wp_terms`, `wp_term_taxonomy` and `wp_termmeta`.
- [ERROR: can not insert term into database](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/error-can-not-insert-term-into-database/). They advise to repair the SQL tables. For this, go to PhpMyAdmin, select all tables. In the "With Selected..." drop-down list, select Repair Table.

Well, I did these things, they did not work for ME. In my case, when I was following some hardening and security tips, I renamed the prefix of my database tables. In this process, I renamed the `wp_term_taxonomy` and `wp_term_relationships` tables to `newprefix_taxonomy` and `newprefix_relationships`, respectively (I've already told that I am not good with SQL, haven't I?). Thus, the `term_` part was lost, and this was causing the error. All I had to do was to rename them to `newprefix_term_taxonomy` and `newprefix_term_relationships`. Renaming the tables can be done in PhpMyAdmin by selecting the table, going to the Operations tab, and renaming it.

This solved my problem, but each case is a separate case.